# Is it possible to convert PPC Assembly to C?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, decompiling, powerpc

i have some PPC code that i want to convert back into its original C code, is there a way to do this? Possibly a person (such as somebody who knows PPC to reconstruct the C code?) or a program?

Comment: You cannot get the *original* C, as compiling to machine code is a lossy process.  There is no 1 to 1 correspondence.  A disassembler/decompiler for Power is outside of my expertise, however.

Comment: It's also a RISC, and this makes reversing much more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

It is possible in principle to translate a program in any language to any other language. The results will not be pretty.

If the existing code really is the result of a compilation without too much clever optimization, then it is likely that a fairly rote process can turn it back to C. This is often straightforward to do by hand for small amounts of code, but tedious and error prone for large code bases.

There are some reverse engineering tools out there in the wild that make claims about decompilation. It isn't an easy problem in the general case.

One approach to automating the problem is to create a PPC assembly (or even binary) front-end for a compiler that already supports a C language back-end. The result is a cross-compiler that reads PPC code and produces highly obfuscated C code. I know there is a C back-end for GCC, for instance.

Regardless of the approach you take, it will likely be critical that you have a good test suite (and the ability to run it) for the existing binary so that you have a means of proving that the translation is equivalent.

**Edit:**  Note that you will never get the original comments back, and will only have access to original variable and function names that made it into a symbol table or similar debug information.

Comment: What i am trying to do is attempt to recover the encryption keys originally stored in the executable. using IDA i got it down to the PPC and there are functions in PPC that directly decrypt and they supposedly store the encryption keys also. If that makes any sense.

Comment: @user: You don't have to "decompile to C" the whole executable just for that. Please update your question.

Comment: Then you are facing a larger challenge. I that were my code, I'd write those functions by hand, using every trick I could find or invent to avoid easy disclosure of the keys. They will not be easy to decompile at all. Your best bet may be simulation of them in operation, and inference of the key values as result of stepping through the live code.

Comment: And I'd take every counter-measure I could find or invent to prevent examination by a live debugger as well. Ask the DVD industry for their opinions about key recovery from products...

Comment: I don't think i have explained the situation well enough. The encryption which was protecting the executable is already bypassed therefore i have the decrypted executable. This executables main function is to decrypt modify re-crypt and send out certain files. So i'm already past the protection of the executable. --Not sure if this makes any sense at all but it's the best way I can think to explain it--

Answer (score 1):

[IDA Pro 6.95](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/compare_ppc.shtml) includes PPC decompiler.
But it is bit costy ($2350)

Answer (score 0):

[Boomerang](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/) claims to support PPC decompilation.

Comment: IDA supports its dissasembly. There is a long way to decompilation into C code.

Comment: Ah, ok - I remove that claim then.

Comment: Boomerang looks pretty cool. Their article on source code recovery is worth reading.

Comment: I checked out Boomerang, it seems to crash every time i use it. I'd also like to note this is a large codebase.

Answer (score 0):

No. Not ever. Decompiling is not the same as getting c back. You can never get c back. You can try reverse engineer it, try to understand what it is doing, but some information is permanently lost.

This is from boomerang project:

> However, a general decompiler does not attempt to reverse every action of the decompiler, rather it transforms the input program repeatedly until the result is high level source code. It therefore **won't recreate** the original source file; **probably nothing like it.**

So it creates some C code that *could be* (but will never know) the C source.

Comment: Of course, in many cases this is sufficient. It can be used to move a legacy binary to a new platform, for instance. Although a simulator of the legacy platform is often a better choice....